# Powershell ActiveDirectory-Module on SBS-2008?

Tags: powershell, windows-sbs-2008

I read plenty of tutorials that describe how to install ADWS (ActiveDirectory Webservices) and Powershell. But I never saw any hint about installing ADWS on a SBS-2008 in order to work with Powershell and ActiveDirectory-module.

I know, that I should use the SBS-Console to manage users, but there are tasks where it could be good to use AD as database of users and computers to loop through them (e.g. remote-commands on all workstations, find out user-lastlogon-times etc).

Can anybody say, if it's ok (and supported?) to install AD-Powershell-Module and ADWS on a SBS-2008? 
Thanks

Comment: If you haven't tried already, I'd ask this at the blog by the team for ad powershell at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adpowershell/. this is the blog of the product group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the first part: ADWS only works on Server 2008 R2. So on that, no it should not work (or at least wouldn't be supported) on SBS 2008.

If you want to use the Active Directory Powershell Module on a 2008 or 2003 Server, you can install the [Active Directory Management Gateway Service](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=2852). So yes, you can get what you want, it just doesn't involve the native ADWS.